# Change the color of the vehicle after reception of a beacon from RSU?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am very new to Omnet++, SUMO and Veins. I am trying to make a simulation where, I transmit beacon from RSU every 10s and after the reception of the beacon the color of the car should change.
I have generated beacons by making changes in omnetpp.ini file as follows:

[image]

In Wave App Layer in omnetpp.ini file I have choosen MyVeinsApp:
[image]

In MyVeinsApp.cc file I have made following Changes:

```
void MyVeinsApp::onBSM(BasicSafetyMessage* bsm)
{
    traciVehicle->setColor(TraCIColor(255,0,0,0));
}
```

But yet I am not able to change the color of the vehicles after the reception of beacons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `findHost()->getDisplayString().setTagArg("i", 1, "green");`